# How can i get element frame to be loaded in android WebViewClient?

Tags: android, webview

Is there any change to get element frame URL to be loaded in
`public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)`? I need it to allow/prevent elements loading from iframes. I know how to prevent/allow but i need to detect if it's event for main frame or child frame element.

Any code line suggestion on where it can be found in chromium source codes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android webView shouldOverrideUrlLoading for iframes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778080/android-webview-shouldoverrideurlloading-for-iframes)

Comment: it's completely another question. i know how to prevent loading but i can't see any possibility to detect if it's main frame event or child frame request

Comment: So `isForMainFrame()`returns always true?https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebResourceRequest.html#isForMainFrame()

Comment: it returns `true` for main frame start loading and `false` otherwise. in fact the first invocation is always for main frame with `true` and all the others with `false` like in the log in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000939/what-is-isformainframe-request-in-android-webviewclient-property-meaning

Comment: Ok, I see, well that is misleading worded in the API. (Retracted duplicate flag.)